# Backward ForeignKey value in list view in django admin

Tags: django, listview, foreign-keys, admin

my models.py file:

```
class Item(models.Model):
  title            = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  slug             = models.SlugField(unique=True, max_length=255)
  item_category    = models.ForeignKey(ItemCategory, blank=True, null=True)
  order            = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  publish          = models.BooleanField(default=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

class ItemMedia(models.Model):
  product         = models.ForeignKey(Item, blank=True, null=True)
  image           = ImageWithThumbsField(upload_to="uploads/products_media", sizes=((936,836),(468,418),(273,243),(59,59)))   
  order           = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
  publish         = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

im trying to show first image in "Items" list view
Thank you

Comment: Maybe you could try to explain what it is you want in more detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class ItemAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'first_image')

    def first_image(self, obj):
        return '<img src="%s"/>' % obj.itemmedia.all()[0].img.url
    first_image.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: worked!the only thing i changed is to add "_set" to "itemmedia" and ".image." instead of ".img." Thank You